# jwplayer onready event is not firing

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

Am using jwplayer 7 enterprise version, while using onReady method in new API format, but the onReady event is not firing all the time.

I don't see any error in console as well.

Following link is the Sample player, please help to resolve this.

http://nithin.nichevid.co.in/player/11434

Comment: I don't see onReady being called here, I only see onSetupError here

Comment: onReady is in the player js file. Sometimes its firing and sometimes not firing. Do i need to put the onReady event as soon as after the setup?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Thanks, You gave me the clue to solve it. as i was having the onReady method not immediately after setup, it was not firing. i have solved that by re ordering my script.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onReady method must be called immediately after setup done. Re ordering the script made it work.